# Spring cloud stream rabbitmq - consumer retries 3 times for all exception

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-rabbit, rabbitmqctl

I am trying to stop the retires for my spring boot cloud application completely or retry for only specific exceptions

I have tried several ways to completely stop it from retrying 3 times I set the following configuration but even then it retires

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.max-attempts=1

spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.input.consumer.requeue-rejected=true
```

To retry for specific exceptions I used below code but didn't work out it still tries to retry for exceptions I don't want to

```
cloud:
      stream:
         rabbit:
            bindings:
               input:
                  consumer:
                     autoBindDlq: true
                     republishToDlq: true
                     prefix: local-
                     maxAttempts: 3
                     backOffInitialInterval: 1000
                     backOffMaxInterval: 10000
                     backOffMultiplier: 2.0
                     defaultRetryable: true
                     retryableExceptions:
                        com.ss.*: true
                        java.lang.*: false
```

Any idea on how to make it not retry or retry for specific exceptions

Comment: We don't support wild cards. "A map of Throwable class names in the key and a boolean in the value. Specify those exceptions (and subclasses) that will or won’t be retried. Also see defaultRetriable. Example: spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.retryable-exceptions.java.lang.IllegalStateException=false.". Also with 'defaultRetriable" don't you actually want to set it to false for your use case?

Comment: Hi Oleg, I was actually giving full exception in code, and I tried defualtRetriable:false

Comment: defaultRetryable: false
                     retryableExceptions:
                        java.lang.RuntimeException: true
                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: false                                      
                     defaultRetryable: false
                     retryableExceptions:
                        java.lang.RuntimeException: true
                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: false